# A generic error occurred in GDI+ simple read and save

Tags: gdi+

I'm encountering a GDI error when trying to save my image. I've looked at lots of solutions and none seem to answer the question. I've created a form with simple load and save buttons.

The load reads using a stream and I'm saving to a new filename. The test create is working so not permissions. The file abctest.jpg is created with 0 bytes.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CheckImageInUse
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    Bitmap originalImage = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var fs = File.OpenRead(@"c:\images\DSC_0005.JPG"))
        { 
            this.originalImage = new Bitmap(fs);
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (File.Create(@"c:\images\testcreate.txt"))
        { }

        this.originalImage.Save(@"c:\images\abctest.jpg");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had a play around and the only way I can see do get this to work is with the following change to the load.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var fs = File.OpenRead(@"c:\images\DSC_0005.JPG"))            
        using (Bitmap tempBitmap = new Bitmap(fs))
        {
            this.originalImage = new Bitmap(tempBitmap);
        }            
    }
```

I think this is to do with linking to the original image on disk and some internal pointers. Creating the fresh copy of the image in memory allows me to save it. A bit of a waste but works.